# Not getting Return value on an asyn / await function

Tags: node.js, async-await, stripe-payments

The function previously using the try and catch method

```
const chargeCard = async (
  stripeToken,
  amount,
  currency,
  phoneNumber,
  animalName,
  numberOfHorses
) => {
  try {
    let charge;
    charge = await to(
      stripe.charges.create({
        amount: amount.replace('.', ''),
        currency: currency,
        description: `Charge from ${phoneNumber} for ${animalName}`,
        source: stripeToken,
        metadata: {
          phoneNumber,
          animalName,
          numberOfHorses
        }
      })
    );
    return charge;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    logger.error(error);
    return error;
  }
};
```

but now i figured out the correct method to get the errors i need to add callback and promise inside the function which is

```
var result = stripe.charges.create({
 ...data...
}, function (err, charge) { // <-- callback
 ...
}).then(function(charge) { // <-- promise
 ...
})
```

with the following  function

```
const chargeCard = async (
  stripeToken,
  amount,
  currency,
  phoneNumber,
  animalName,
  numberOfHorses
) => {

  try {
    const charge = await
    stripe.charges.create({
      amount: amount.replace('.', ''),
      currency: currency,
      description: `Charge from ${phoneNumber} for ${animalName}`,
      source: stripeToken,
      metadata: {
        phoneNumber,
        animalName,
        numberOfHorses
      }
    }, (error, charge) => {
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    }).then(charge => charge);
    // return charge;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    logger.error(error);
    return error;
  }
}
```

its getting all the errors when i'm logging into the console but its not returning the errors by calling this chargeCard function.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That looks a bit strange, does `.create` really return a `Promise` *and* take a callback?

Comment: Please check again i have updated the code.

Comment: Generally if a function takes a callback it doesn't return a promise. There are APIs that provide both method but usually if the callback exists then the promise is not returned. So either do `.create(options, (err, result) => {})` or do `.create(options).then(result=>{}).catch(err=>{})`

Comment: Let me Try this

Comment: Its still not returning anything its showing undefined only.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? it should work

```
const chargeCard = async (
  stripeToken,
  amount,
  currency,
  phoneNumber,
  animalName,
  numberOfHorses
) => {

  try {
    const charge = await
    stripe.charges.create({
      amount: amount.replace('.', ''),
      currency: currency,
      description: `Charge from ${phoneNumber} for ${animalName}`,
      source: stripeToken,
      metadata: {
        phoneNumber,
        animalName,
        numberOfHorses
      }
    });
    return charge;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    logger.error(error);
    return error;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I created my service:

```
  let paymentResult = undefined

  try {
    paymentResult = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: defaultAmount,
      currency,
      source: paymentInfo.id,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Payment error: \nHEADER:${JSON.stringify(requestHeader)} \nSTRIPE ERROR:${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
    paymentResult = { error: error.type }
  }

  return paymentResult
```

As you can see no callback was needed as I return the success payload or errors simply using async/await and try/catch structures.